# Up to date Mint and AMD/ATI Radeon 2600 HD Mobility

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, ati, amd

I just installed Linux Mint (3.11 Kernel) on a 2007 Notebook with a Radeon 2600 HD Mobility. Works fine so far, but is there any chance I can use propritary drivers for this GPU?

What will happen if I just install `fglrx` with the Synaptics package manager? Will it warn me if my GPU is not supported?

I'm asking because Manjaro Linux (based on Arch Linux) has a simple tool to install `catalyst-legacy` (even on Kernel 3.12), so I was wondering how to do this on Mint.

Comment: Just in case the tools show you version numbers: latest driver for your GPU is the [legacy r13.1 driver](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy2&os=Linux%20x86), newest overall is [r13.12](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86).

Comment: I already downloaded the .run file from AMD, using the Website tools to select the right driver. It gives me the 13.1 driver. But when startung the run file and selecting "Install driver" it stops. The log files say that `fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers.  /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.` - But I have the Kernel headers installed - the directory is full of files, only "version.h" is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Mint has its own tool to install propitiatory drivers, I recommend you use it. 
I haven't used Mint in a while but if memory serves, it should be available in the menu => control center => Additional Drivers. That should bring up a window like this one (taken from [here](http://www.linuxandlife.com/2013/07/things-to-do-after-installing-linux-mint.html)):

[image]

Just hit the Activate button to install the one you want. If this does not work, update your question or post a new one to solve any issues :).

Comment: I had this open already. My driver window looks slightly different (it's called "Driver Manager"). And it is empty (just the close button in top right corner is active). It does not provide any drivers.