# How to compile AMD Legacy driver on 64-bit kernel, Linux Mint 17

Tags: linux-mint, compiling, kernel-modules, fglrx

I'm trying to get the legacy driver for my HD 2400 GPU but I had an error while it was building.

I looked at this answer, and have the same result, in the driver manager is empty:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106918/72663

In order to get past the missing `version.h` file I did this first:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
```

When I run the catalyst tool to install the driver I'm getting this:

```
Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.97.100.7/source ->
                 /usr/src/fglrx-8.97.100.7

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
cd /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.97.100.7/build; sh make.sh --nohints --uname_r=3.13.0-24-generic --norootcheck....(bad exit status: 1)
[Error] Kernel Module : Failed to build fglrx-8.97.100.7 with DKMS
[Error] Kernel Module : Removing fglrx-8.97.100.7 from DKMS
```

But I believe the problem is that `version.h` has moved, so this is all of my locations:

```
$ sudo find / -name version.h/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/include/VBox/version.h
/lib/firmware/carl9170fw/include/shared/version.h
/usr/include/linux/version.h
/usr/include/linux/dvb/version.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic/include/config/arch/want/ipc/parse/version.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic/include/config/evm/hmac/version.h
/usr/src/virtualbox-guest-4.3.10/include/VBox/version.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24/include/uapi/linux/dvb/version.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24/include/xen/interface/version.h
```

I installed the 32-bit version of the kernel headers as seen here:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic:i386 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 208 not upgraded.
```

I expect I need to change something in `make.sh` to fix the path, but I'm not certain what I should change, or just do an `ln -s ...` to get it to work easily.

With a 64-bit 3.13.0 kernel, how do I install fglrx-8.97.100.7?  If I can't get this to work with Mint Linux, would this be simpler with Ubuntu?

I'm doing some programming with WebGL and can't get the acceleration I need to test my javascript code with the generic driver.

Comment: Why exactly you created the symlink? From where you obtained the drivers? Don't `radeon` drivers work?

Comment: Could you find the actual error message in the build log file and include that?